# Batch script to find a pattern and put in variable

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

Currently I am trying to extract the most important information from a `.html` file with a batch script. To be more specific, I need to print something that I will write as `ї`, so `ї` - is the information I need.
The script must find a pattern `<a href="їїї">її</a>` and get `їїї` and `її` from it. Find a pattern everywhere in a file e.g. `file.html` and print `їїї` and `її`.

I would be particularly grateful if you could also explain me how your code works in detail.

What I have done:

```
findstr "<a href=" file.html
```

It will find a string with a pattern but I don't know how to put that in a variable and proceed it later to get rid of `<a href="`, `">` and `</a>`

also I have tried to use `for /f "tokens=1,2delims=<a href=""` but there is an error with quotation marks. It recognise the `"` after `href=` as an opening quotation mark

A option with regex is not a solution. But write to me if you have an idea how that can be done.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==<>" %%a in ('type file.html^|findstr /ilc:"<a href="') do echo %%~a, %%b`, but you won't be satisfied. Batch is able to work with pure text files (ANSI/ASCII) but your `.html` is probably encoded as UTF.

Comment: `delims` delimits at each character, in your case at each `<`, `a`,  `h`, `r`, `e`, `f`, and `=` (and each space, if you put it as the last character; at the position you put it, it generates a syntax error). That's probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter **FIND.EXE** to print proper lines then parse them all by **FOR**.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=2 tokens=2* delims== " %%A in (`find/i"<a href=" file.htm`) do (
 set "string=%%B"
 set a=!string:^>=_!
 set b=!a:^<=_!
 for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%i in ("!b!") do echo %%~i %%j 
)
endlocal
```

This code example doesn't check for improper values or split strings. So turn your solutions into the Powershell.

Comment: Deamon-5 thank you for your answer. Could you also say how to get rid of quotation mark in printed result and how to print the second її. Currently it prints only first part їїї but it is important for me to output її too (the part before < / a >)